# wrong number or types of arguments in call

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

i am trying to call stored procedure from my spring project. this stored procedure tries to insert some values in table and returns some string if it fails to insert data. e.g Bank code and deposit slip no already exists

**Dao class**

```
@Repository
public class PaymentDaoImpl implements PaymentDao {


    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session;
    private Transaction trans;

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy ");
    Date date = new Date();

    public void savePayments(PaymentParams paymentParams) {
    try {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    trans = session.beginTransaction();
    System.out.println("date format");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

Query<Object[]> query = session.createNativeQuery 
("CALLPROC_INS_RMIS_BNK_VCHER_TABLE
(:P_BUD_YEAR,:P_DISTRICT_CODE,:P_TRAN_NDATE,:P_TRAN_EDATE,:P_BANK_CODE,
:P_DEPOSIT_BANK_CODE,:P_PO_CODE,:P_ECONOMIC_CODE5,:P_AMOUNT,:P_PAN,
:P_PAYEE_NAME,:P_PAYEE_ADD,:P_PHONE_NO,:P_TAX_YEAR,:P_PAYMENT_TYPE,:P_CHEQUE_DRAFT_NO,                  
:P_DATETIME,:P_CREATED_BY,:P_TAX_FLAG,:P_CLEARANCE_EDATE,:P_CLEARANCE_NDATE,
:P_VOUCHER_NO,:P_CHEQUE_TYPE,:P_CHE_DRA_ISSUE_BANK,                   
:P_VOUCHER_STATUS,:P_RECORD_LOCK_FLAG,:P_VOUCHER_DATE,:P_ADJUST_FLAG,
:P_VOUCHER_NDATE,:P_DEPOSIT_SLIP_NO,:P_COUNTER_CODE,:P_UPDATE_DATETIME,                    
:P_UPDATE_BY,:P_PO_AMDANI_FLAG,:P_DOLLAR_AMOUNT,:P_UPDATE_NDATE,
:P_DEPOSIT_SLIP_AUTO,:P_TRAN_BUD_YEAR,:p_error_code)")
         .setParameter("P_BUD_YEAR", "2071/72")  
         .setParameter("P_DISTRICT_CODE", "28") 
         .setParameter("P_TRAN_NDATE", "2071-04-01") 
         .setParameter("P_TRAN_EDATE", dateFormat.format(date))
         .setParameter("P_BANK_CODE", "11001016") //5
         .setParameter("P_DEPOSIT_BANK_CODE", "11001016")
         .setParameter("P_PO_CODE", "28-204-02") //7
         .setParameter("P_ECONOMIC_CODE5", "14221") 
         .setParameter("P_AMOUNT", 132) 
         .setParameter("P_PAN", null) 
         .setParameter("P_PAYEE_NAME", "पुनरावेदन अदा") 
         .setParameter("P_PAYEE_ADD", "Patan") 
         .setParameter("P_PHONE_NO", "553658")  
         .setParameter("P_TAX_YEAR", "2071/72") 
         .setParameter("P_PAYMENT_TYPE", "A")  
         .setParameter("P_CHEQUE_DRAFT_NO", null) 
         .setParameter("P_DATETIME", dateFormat.format(date)) 
         .setParameter("P_CREATED_BY", "GBL001")
         .setParameter("P_TAX_FLAG", "N")
         .setParameter("P_CLEARANCE_EDATE", dateFormat.format(date)) 
         .setParameter("P_CLEARANCE_NDATE", "2071-04-01") 
         .setParameter("P_VOUCHER_NO", "00000001") 
         .setParameter("P_CHEQUE_TYPE", null)
         .setParameter("P_CHE_DRA_ISSUE_BANK", null) 
         .setParameter("P_VOUCHER_STATUS", "T")
         .setParameter("P_RECORD_LOCK_FLAG", "Y")
         .setParameter("P_VOUCHER_DATE", dateFormat.format(date)) 
         .setParameter("P_ADJUST_FLAG", "N")
         .setParameter("P_VOUCHER_NDATE", "2071-04-01") 
         .setParameter("P_DEPOSIT_SLIP_NO", 25764132) 
         .setParameter("P_COUNTER_CODE", "P3") 
         .setParameter("P_UPDATE_DATETIME", dateFormat.format(date))
        .setParameter("P_UPDATE_BY", "D00265")
        .setParameter("P_PO_AMDANI_FLAG", "Y") 
        .setParameter("P_DOLLAR_AMOUNT", 0) 
        .setParameter("P_UPDATE_NDATE", "2073-04-03") 
        .setParameter("P_DEPOSIT_SLIP_AUTO", "N") 
        .setParameter("P_TRAN_BUD_YEAR", "2073/74") 
        .setParameter("p_error_code", null); 

         List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();
            for (Object[] obj : list) {
                System.out.println("result" + obj[0]);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

**query to execute stored procedure:**

at the moment this stored procedure when executing on sql developer fails to insert data so it returns text "Bank code and deposit slip no already exists". i need to fetch exactly this returned text.

```
  DECLARE
       v_error_code   VARCHAR2 (250);
       v_voucher_no   VARCHAR2 (250);

BEGIN
   RMIS7172.PROC_INS_RMIS_BNK_VCHER_TABLE (
      P_BUD_YEAR             => '2071/72',
      P_DISTRICT_CODE        => '28',
      P_TRAN_NDATE           => '2071-04-01',
      P_TRAN_EDATE           => '09-Jul-2017',
      P_BANK_CODE            => '11001016',
      P_DEPOSIT_BANK_CODE    => '11001016',
      P_PO_CODE              => '28-204-02',
      P_ECONOMIC_CODE5       => '14221',
      P_AMOUNT               => 132,
      P_PAN                  => NULL,
      P_PAYEE_NAME           => 'पुनरावेदन अदा',
      P_PAYEE_ADD            => 'Patan',
      P_PHONE_NO             => '553658',
      P_TAX_YEAR             => '2071/72',
      P_PAYMENT_TYPE         => 'A',
      P_CHEQUE_DRAFT_NO      => NULL,
      P_DATETIME             => SYSDATE,
      P_CREATED_BY           => 'GBL001',
      P_TAX_FLAG             => 'N',
      P_CLEARANCE_EDATE      => '17-jul-2017',
      P_CLEARANCE_NDATE      => '2071-04-01',
      P_VOUCHER_NO           => v_voucher_no,
      P_CHEQUE_TYPE          => NULL,
      P_CHE_DRA_ISSUE_BANK   => NULL,
      P_VOUCHER_STATUS       => 'T',
      P_RECORD_LOCK_FLAG     => 'Y',
      P_VOUCHER_DATE         => SYSDATE,
      P_ADJUST_FLAG          => 'N',
      P_VOUCHER_NDATE        => '2071-04-01',
      P_DEPOSIT_SLIP_NO      => '25764132',
      P_COUNTER_CODE         => 'P3',
      P_UPDATE_DATETIME      => SYSDATE,
      P_UPDATE_BY            => 'D00265',
      P_PO_AMDANI_FLAG       => 'Y',
      P_DOLLAR_AMOUNT        => 0,
      P_UPDATE_NDATE         => '2073-04-03',
      P_DEPOSIT_SLIP_AUTO    => 'N',
      P_TRAN_BUD_YEAR        => '2073/74',
      p_error_code           => v_error_code);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_error_code);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_voucher_no);

END;
```

but it throws error:-

```
 SQL Error: 6553, SQLState: 65000
 ERROR:: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments
 in call to 'PROC_INS_RMIS_BNK_VCHER_TABLE'
```

**stored procedure**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE          PROC_INS_RMIS_BNK_VCHER_TABLE (
   P_BUD_YEAR                  VARCHAR2,
   P_DISTRICT_CODE             VARCHAR2,                            --NOT NULL
   P_TRAN_NDATE                VARCHAR2,                            --NOT NULL
   P_TRAN_EDATE                DATE,
   P_BANK_CODE                 VARCHAR2,                             --NOT NULL
   P_DEPOSIT_BANK_CODE         VARCHAR2,                            --NOT NULL
   P_PO_CODE                   VARCHAR2,                            --NOT NULL
   P_ECONOMIC_CODE5            VARCHAR2,                            --NOT NULL
   P_AMOUNT                    NUMBER,
   P_PAN                       NUMBER,
   P_PAYEE_NAME                NVARCHAR2,
   P_PAYEE_ADD                 NVARCHAR2,
   P_PHONE_NO                  VARCHAR2,
   P_TAX_YEAR                  VARCHAR2,                            --NOT NULL
   P_PAYMENT_TYPE              CHAR,                                --NOT NULL
   P_CHEQUE_DRAFT_NO           VARCHAR2,
   P_DATETIME                  DATE,
   P_CREATED_BY                VARCHAR2,                            --NOT NULL
   P_TAX_FLAG                  CHAR,                                --NOT NULL
   P_CLEARANCE_EDATE           DATE,
   P_CLEARANCE_NDATE           VARCHAR2,
   P_VOUCHER_NO            OUT VARCHAR2,

   P_CHEQUE_TYPE               CHAR,
   P_CHE_DRA_ISSUE_BANK        VARCHAR2,
   P_VOUCHER_STATUS            CHAR,                                --NOT NULL
   P_RECORD_LOCK_FLAG          CHAR,                                --NOT NULL
   P_VOUCHER_DATE              DATE,
   P_ADJUST_FLAG               CHAR,                                --NOT NULL
   P_VOUCHER_NDATE             CHAR,                                --NOT NULL
   P_DEPOSIT_SLIP_NO           NUMBER,
   P_COUNTER_CODE              VARCHAR2,                            --NOT NULL

   P_UPDATE_DATETIME           DATE,
   P_UPDATE_BY                 VARCHAR2,
   P_PO_AMDANI_FLAG            CHAR,
   P_DOLLAR_AMOUNT             NUMBER,

   P_UPDATE_NDATE              VARCHAR2,
   P_DEPOSIT_SLIP_AUTO         CHAR,
   P_TRAN_BUD_YEAR             VARCHAR2,
   p_error_code            OUT VARCHAR2                             --NOT NULL
                                       --not null
   )
IS
   v_date                DATE;
   v_check_date          DATE;
   v_count               NUMBER (1);
   v_ret                 PLS_INTEGER;
   v_same_day_check      CHAR (1);
   v_error_code          VARCHAR2 (2500):=null;
   v_SUB_DISTRICT_CODE   VARCHAR2 (250);
   v_MAIN_BANK_CODE      VARCHAR2 (250);
   v_bank_account_no_nep varchar2(250);
   v_sno number;
BEGIN
   SELECT SUBSTR (p_BANK_CODE, 1, 5) INTO v_MAIN_BANK_CODE FROM DUAL;

   P_VOUCHER_NO := NULL;

   v_date := TO_DATE (SYSDATE) - 1;

   begin
        SELECT count(voucher_no)
        INTO v_count
        FROM rmis7172.BANK_VOUCHER
       WHERE     main_bank_code = v_main_bank_code
       AND deposit_slip_no = p_deposit_slip_no;
           if v_count>=1 then  
              v_error_code:='Bank code and deposit slip no already exists';
           end if;
   end; 

   v_count:=0;   




                BEGIN
                select bank_account_no_nep INTO v_bank_account_no_nep FROM RMIS_V_BANK
                WHERE BANK_CODE=p_BANK_CODE;
                EXCEPTION
                    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                    v_bank_account_no_nep:=NULL;
                    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
                    v_bank_account_no_nep:=NULL;
                END ;



   FOR i IN 1 .. 30
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         SELECT holiday_date
           INTO v_check_date
           FROM S_HOLIDAY_PARAMETER
          WHERE v_date = TO_DATE (holiday_date);

         v_date := v_date - 1;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
         THEN
            EXIT;
            NULL;
      END;
   END LOOP;


   ---------------------------------------------------------

   IF P_BANK_CODE IS NOT NULL AND V_BANK_ACCOUNT_NO_NEP IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      BEGIN
         BEGIN
            SELECT COUNT (*)
              INTO v_count
              FROM rmis7172.RMIS_DAY_CLOSE
             WHERE     bank_code = P_BANK_CODE
                   AND bank_account_no_nep = v_BANK_ACCOUNT_NO_NEP
                   AND tran_edate = TO_DATE (v_date);
         EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
            THEN
               v_error_code := ':Data not found in day close table:';
         END;
      END;



      -- CHECK DAY CLOSE OF SAME DATE


      BEGIN
         SELECT 'X'
           INTO v_same_day_check
           FROM rmis7172.RMIS_DAY_CLOSE
          WHERE     bank_code = p_bank_code
                AND bank_account_no_nep = v_BANK_ACCOUNT_NO_NEP
                AND from_edate = p_tran_edate;

         v_error_code := ':Day Close has already done:';
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
         THEN
            NULL;
      END;
   ELSE
      v_error_code :=
         ':P_BANK_CODE is null or/and P_BANK_ACCOUNT_NO_NEP is null:';
   END IF;



   IF p_bank_code IS NULL
   THEN
      v_error_code := v_error_code || ':Bank is null:';

      NULL;
   END IF;

   IF v_bank_account_no_nep IS NULL
   THEN
      v_error_code := v_error_code || ':Account No is null:';
   END IF;

   IF P_deposit_slip_no IS NULL
   THEN
      v_error_code := v_error_code || ':Deposit slip No is null:';
   END IF;

   IF P_amount IS NULL
   THEN
      v_error_code := v_error_code || ':Amount is null:';
   END IF;

   IF P_economic_code5 IS NULL
   THEN
      v_error_code := v_error_code || ':Revenue Head is null:';
   END IF;

   IF P_po_code IS NULL
   THEN
      v_error_code := v_error_code || ':Paying Office is null:';
   END IF;

   IF P_PAYEE_NAME IS NULL
   THEN
      v_error_code := v_error_code || ':Payee  Name is null:';
   END IF;


   IF P_payment_type <> 'A'
   THEN
      IF p_cheque_type IS NULL
      THEN
         v_error_code := ':Cheque Type is null:';
      END IF;

      IF P_CHE_DRA_ISSUE_BANK IS NULL
      THEN
         v_error_code := ':Cheque / Draft Issue Bank is null:';
      END IF;

      IF P_CHEQUE_DRAFT_NO IS NULL
      THEN
         v_error_code := ':Cheque / Draft No is null:';
      END IF;
   END IF;

   IF v_error_code IS NULL
   THEN
      SELECT NVL (MAX (SNO), 0) + 1
        INTO v_SNO
        FROM BANK_VOUCHER
       WHERE created_by = p_created_by;



      BEGIN
         SELECT sub_district_code
           INTO v_SUB_DISTRICT_CODE
           FROM RMIS_V_BANK
          WHERE     bank_code = p_bank_code
                AND bank_account_no_nep = v_bank_account_no_nep;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
         THEN
            NULL;
      END;

      INSERT INTO rmis7172.BANK_VOUCHER (BUD_YEAR,
                                          DISTRICT_CODE,
                                          SUB_DISTRICT_CODE,
                                          TRAN_NDATE,
                                          TRAN_EDATE,
                                          BANK_CODE,
                                          DEPOSIT_BANK_CODE,
                                          PO_CODE,
                                          ECONOMIC_CODE5,
                                          AMOUNT,
                                          PAN,
                                          PAYEE_NAME,
                                          PAYEE_ADD,
                                          PHONE_NO,
                                          TAX_YEAR,
                                          PAYMENT_TYPE,
                                          CHEQUE_DRAFT_NO,
                                          DATETIME,
                                          CREATED_BY,
                                          TAX_FLAG,
                                          CLEARANCE_EDATE,
                                          CLEARANCE_NDATE,
                                          VOUCHER_NO,
                                                                                    CHEQUE_TYPE,
                                          CHE_DRA_ISSUE_BANK,
                                          VOUCHER_STATUS,
                                          RECORD_LOCK_FLAG,
                                          VOUCHER_DATE,
                                          ADJUST_FLAG,
                                          VOUCHER_NDATE,
                                          DEPOSIT_SLIp_NO,
                                          SNO,
                                          COUNTER_CODE,

                                          MAIN_BANK_CODE,
                                          UPDATE_DATETIME,
                                          UPDATE_BY,
                                          PO_AMDANI_FLAG,
                                          DOLLAR_AMOUNT,

                                          UPDATE_NDATE,
                                          DEPOSIT_SLIp_AUTO,
                                          TRAN_BUD_YEAR)
           VALUES (P_BUD_YEAR,
                   P_DISTRICT_CODE,
                   v_SUB_DISTRICT_CODE,
                   P_TRAN_NDATE,
                   P_TRAN_EDATE,
                   P_BANK_CODE,
                   P_DEPOSIT_BANK_CODE,
                   P_PO_CODE,
                   P_ECONOMIC_CODE5,
                   P_AMOUNT,
                   P_PAN,
                   P_PAYEE_NAME,
                   P_PAYEE_ADD,
                   P_PHONE_NO,
                   P_TAX_YEAR,
                   P_PAYMENT_TYPE,
                   P_CHEQUE_DRAFT_NO,
                   P_DATETIME,
                   P_CREATED_BY,
                   P_TAX_FLAG,
                   P_CLEARANCE_EDATE,
                   P_CLEARANCE_NDATE,
                   P_VOUCHER_NO,

                   P_CHEQUE_TYPE,
                   P_CHE_DRA_ISSUE_BANK,
                   P_VOUCHER_STATUS,
                   P_RECORD_LOCK_FLAG,
                   P_VOUCHER_DATE,
                   P_ADJUST_FLAG,
                   P_VOUCHER_NDATE,
                   P_DEPOSIT_SLIP_NO,
                   v_SNO,
                   P_COUNTER_CODE,

                   v_MAIN_BANK_CODE,
                   P_UPDATE_DATETIME,
                   P_UPDATE_BY,
                   P_PO_AMDANI_FLAG,
                   P_DOLLAR_AMOUNT,

                   P_UPDATE_NDATE,
                   P_DEPOSIT_SLIP_AUTO,
                   P_TRAN_BUD_YEAR);

      COMMIT;

      SELECT voucher_no
        INTO P_VOUCHER_NO
        FROM rmis7172.BANK_VOUCHER
       WHERE     main_bank_code = v_main_bank_code
             AND deposit_slip_no = p_deposit_slip_no;
   ELSE
      p_error_code := v_error_code;
   END IF;
END;
```

i tried to figure out what data types my table accepts. apart from date(not sure if above method of passing date as parameter is correct) the values i passed from my dao class matches the data types my table accepts.
my questions are:-

1. am i passing date parameter in correct way?
2. am i calling stored procedure in correct way?

Comment: are u using date datatype in table

Comment: yes those are date data types

Comment: For input and output of dates, the standard Oracle date format is DD-MON-YY,

Comment: Please add code of your procedure-
 `PROC_INS_RMIS_BNK_VCHER_TABLE` in the question.

Comment: please check store procedure as well